# PHP send link to get file

Tags: php

i'am a php beginner and i want to solve my problem

```
    $web = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$inj = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$target = rawurldecode($web.$inj);
file_get_contents("http://myserver.com/get.php?url={$target}");
```

i want to include this source to a php script file, and anytime this file is executed he will send the url link to myserver.com/get.php (an outside server)

and i need help in get.php what should i write inside..
Thanks in advance and sorry for my english